# QGIS Globe UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ubuntu, globe

My QGIS Globe is not working: After starting it, that massage pops up in a endless loop:

> UnsupportedOperationException: GeometryGraph::add(Geometry &): unknown
>   geometry type: N4geos4geom7PolygonE

Im using xubuntu 12.04, QGIS 1.8.0, ATI graphic card and AMD X2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QGIS Globe wiki page mentions the following.

> The following aspects of the globe should be reviewed for stability:
>
> - Multithreaded QGIS core: The globe was developed based on Martins threading branch. Since there are now basic locks to avoid parallel rendering, the globe can be run without a multithreaded QGIS core.
> - OSG-QT OpenGL adapter: The original QT adapater from OSG got updates
>   in the meantime and OsgEarth includes a QT binding in its newest
>   version.
> - **OSG version compatibility: Some stablity problems could be
>   caused by specific library versions**.
> - Dynamic layer configuration:
>   OSGEarth support for adding, updating and deleting (DEM or QGIS tile)
>   layers dynamically is improving. QGIS globe should be adapted to the
>   newest OSGEarth version.
> - Plugin startup and cleanup: There are
>   problems on startup (window for OpenGL capability detection e.g.) and
>   in cleaning up after layer updates or closing the globe window.

Your problem is caused by the OpenSceneGraph libraries as evidenced by your error message. It's on the [QGIS issue tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4053) as well. There's no solution as of this writing.